# How to prevent elements from moving upwards while resizing the page vertically

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I am learning front end web development and i was trying to make Netflix clone and its going smoothly until i resize my page vertically, the main tagline of the page moves upward as i keep decreasing the size vertically.
Can someone help me to figure it out, how to make it static like the original Netflix sign up page.
I hope you understand what i am trying to say!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cYgQs0d4PLP4fzSRlMM1wN8jWu_55XyD?usp=share_link

i have uploaded a folder containing my files html and css.
I know its messy and unresponsive but i will fix that later as a pioneer that'a great progress for me so please help me to find a solution.

Comment: kindly post your full code..including HTML...better if you include jsfiddle snippet...it will help us understand the problem better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your .info class, position:absolute with top:50% is what is causing the movement of info bar.

Unless necessary, you should minimize the use position:absolute, it breaks the 'flow' of document and messes with a lot of things you might be unaware about.

An easy workaround is as follows:

```
.info{
  margin:auto;
  width:50vw;
}
```

I am sure there are better workarounds but the basic idea is to preserve the  [Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) of document.